# Causing a seg fault in C | Heap stack virtual memory

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory, virtual-memory, stack-memory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *ptr;

  while(1){ 
    ++ptr; 
    printf("%p\n", ptr); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Question: Your code should increment a pointer that points at the
heap, by 1 byte, repeatedly, until the program crashes.

I'm trying to create a segfault by iterating over all addresses in the stack, one byte at a time. However, the code just keeps running and doesn't cause a segmentation fault. How could I change it to cause a segfault?

Comment: You never dereference the pointer. If you want a segfault, just do `*((int*)0);`

Comment: Even though not dereferenced, it is *undefined behaviour* since `ptr` is unintialised.

Comment: I think you must use `malloc()` to use pointer that refers to Heap. `ptr= malloc()` obtain desired memory location at heap, then you can access to heap with ptr pointer.

Comment: As I understand it from your question, you're asking for 2 different things. You can point at the heap and increment that until it crashes, or you can point somewhere on the stack and increment that until it crashes. Which one do you want?

Comment: Both stack and heap actually

Comment: This really depends on what hardware and compiler you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a pointer that points to the stack, set it to the address of a local variable:

```
int main() {
    int object;
    int *p = &object;
```

However, simply incrementing a pointer will not cause a segmentation fault. To get a segmentation fault you need to dereference an invalid pointer. So the loop should be like:

```
    while(1) {
        ++ptr;
        printf("%p %d\n", ptr, *ptr);
    }
```

Trying to print `*ptr` will eventually cause the fault.

For the heap you can do it similarly, but initialize `p` with a call to `malloc()` instead of the address of a local variable.

Comment: Why can't you loop over every address? Wouldn't accessing every address, setting a value, eventually cause it to run out?

Comment: In a virtual memory system, most addresses aren't mapped, or some of them are protected because they're part of the kernel. So eventually you hit a block that isn't accessible, and that's what causes a segmentation violation.

Comment: What sets the value for how many iterations the while loop will run for? Say it runs 500 times before the segmentation fault, why did it run 500 times rather than 1000 times?

Comment: It's dependent on how the process memory is laid out by the operating system and C runtime library. You get the error when you run into the first unmapped address page.

Comment: It seems like you need to read about how process memory is implemented.

Comment: @TrevorGood Because it just happened (by coincidence!) that `&object+499` was a valid readable address but `&object+500` wasn't.